# runtime error / file not found-Android

Tags: android, genymotion, absolute-path

I am beginner to android
I am working on a project in which I have to read images and process them
the problem is I am not able to give the right path in the code
and this is because I use Genymotion emulator , I am not dealing with real device
the file is stored in the internal storage>0>DCIM>Camera>IMG_NAME
and I use the following code

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);}
 _path=Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            _path=_path+"/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151204_043744.jpg";
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);
}
```

the error line I get from my logcat:

```
12-04 08:57:37.409    1482-1482/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151204_043744.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

could anyone please help me defining the correct path in the genymotion virtual device.?

Comment: Remove /data from that path.

Comment: @greenapps there is no "/data' in the path

Comment: 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151204_043744.jpg'. Well what did i see there?

Comment: this s from the logcat, if you look at the java code you see: "/emulated/0/DCIM...... @greenapps

Comment: You better believe the logcat. And _path will contain /data.